# UI5 NumericHeader throws error for missed property

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to add a NumericHeader to my UI5 app using this code :

```
<f:Card >
    <f:header>
        <card:NumericHeader title="Title"  />
    </f:header>
</f:Card>
```

But I'm getting this error: *

```
CardActions.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'None' of undefined
    at CardActions.js:6

The only mandatory property for NumericHeader is title.
```

UPDATE :

It's due to the latest version of ui5 , It works fine for the older versions.

Comment: Add a full xml, we can't guess namespaces. Maybe a sample with plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE :

It's due to the latest version of ui5 , It works fine for the older versions.